# ZXing-1.7 Sample implementation issue

Tags: zxing

I recently started a small project in which I wanted to use zxing. I downloaded the sources from [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list). I was able to successfully build the core and the javase jars.

When I tried to code along the sample provided [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/DeveloperNotes) I ran into a problem I do not quite understand. So far the code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
   ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(SOMEPATH);
   Image image = imageIcon.getImage();

   BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage(
      image.getWidth(null), 
      image.getHeight(null), 
   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

   Graphics2D g = buffImage.createGraphics();
   g.drawImage(image, null, null);

   LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(buffImage);
   BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
}
```

As you can see this is pretty much the same code as presented in the DevelopersNotes. But the code will not compile. The error message is:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from BufferedImageLuminanceSource to LuminanceSource
```

Does somebody know what I am missing?

Edit:
My imports are currently looking like this:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
import com.google.zxing.Reader;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
```

I added the core.jar as well as the javase.jar to my project. Both I compiled using ant leaving the buildfiles as downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's all correct. You must have some funny business in your imports. Those types are certainly compatible.

Comment: did you modify any of the code? still looks right. Any chance there are conflicting versions of the code? What line does the error occur on -- there are two possibilities here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this definitely has to work. After reading your answer I went to ant clean the compiled jars and recompiled them. It works :)